# javascript regular expression matching cityname

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following array of data named cityList:

```
 var cityList = [

     "Anaa, French Polynesia (AAA)",
     "Arrabury, Australia (AAB)",
     "Al Arish, Egypt (AAC)",
     "Ad-Dabbah, Sudan (AAD)",
     "Annaba, Algeria (AAE)",
     "Apalachicola, United States (AAF)",
     "Arapoti, Brazil (AAG)",
     "Aachen, Germany (AAH)",
     "Arraias, Brazil (AAI)",
     "Awaradam, Suriname (AAJ)",
     "Aranuka, Kiribati (AAK)",
     "Aalborg, Denmark (AAL)"
 ];
```

I want to first search the city name starting at the beginning of the string.

Next I want to search the code portion of the string: AAA, AAB, AAC, etc...

I want to apply a search pattern as a javascript regular expression, first to the city name, and second to the city code.

Here are my regular expressions:

```
 //  this regular expression used for search city name
 var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");

 //  this regular expression used for search city code
 var matcher = new RegExp("([(*)])" + re, "i");
```

How do I combine these two regular expressions into a single regex that works as described?

Comment: `var matcher`, `var matcher` ??

Comment: second var matcher line is commented.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Looks like yet another recipe for an order form where the prospective customer gives up in disgust at the last step after already committing to a purchase because  a misdirected "validation" attempt denies perfectly valid information.

Comment: I believe he wants to get a search pattern from a user and attempt to use it to search the above strings, which are probably options in a dropdown menu.

Comment: Sad truth: there is no such a regex. Regex just matches strings consisting of specific characters or sequences of characters, it has no idea if some string is a city or human name. You would need to compile a list of all cities and then build a regex TRIE out of it. Else, you might as well simply have a list of cities and check if they are present in the string.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest this:

```
var myregexp = /^([^,]+),[^(]*\(([^()]+)\)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    city = match[1];
    code = match[2];
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
(        # Match and capture (group number 1):
 [^,]+   # One or more characters except comma (alternatively insert city name)
)        # End of group 1
,        # Match a comma
[^(]*    # Match any number of characters except an opening parenthesis
\(       # Match an opening parenthesis
(        # Match and capture (group number 2):
 [^()]+  # One or more characters except parentheses (alt. insert city code)
)        # End of group 2
\)       # Match a closing parenthesis
```

This assumes that no city name will ever contain a comma (otherwise this regex would only capture the part before the comma), so you'd need to check your data if that's ever possible. I can't think of an example, but that's not saying anything :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#leavingCity").autocomplete({ 
source: function(req, responseFn) {
            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
            var matcher = new RegExp("/^([^,]+),[^(]*\(([^()]+)\)/", "g"); 
            var a = $.grep(cityList, function(item,index) { return matcher.test(item); }); 
            responseFn(a); 
} });
```

Try this, regualr expression by Tim Pietzcker

Comment: jQuery and Autocomplete plug-in required.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most elegant way I can do it:

```
var cityList = ["Anaa, French Polynesia (AAA)","Arrabury, Australia (AAB)","Al Arish, Egypt (AAC)","Ad-Dabbah, Sudan (AAD)","Annaba, Algeria (AAE)","Apalachicola, United States (AAF)","Arapoti, Brazil (AAG)","Aachen, Germany (AAH)","Arraias, Brazil (AAI)","Awaradam, Suriname (AAJ)","Aranuka, Kiribati (AAK)","Aalborg, Denmark (AAL)"];
var regex = /([a-z].+?),.+?\(([A-Z]{3,3})\)/gi, match, newList = [];

while (match = regex.exec(cityList)) {
    newList.push(match[1]+" - "+match[2]);
}

alert(newList[7]);
// prints Aachen - AAH
```

If you don't understand how to use parentheses in your regex, I suggest you check out the site I learned from: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 1):

Here I suggest a completly different approach (ECMA-262 standard).

As using the regex requires a linear search anyway, if you can pre-process the data, you can set up an array of city objects:

```
function City(name, country, code){
  this.cityName = name;
  this.cityCountry = country;
  this.cityCode = code;
}

var cities = [];
cities.push(new City('Anaa', 'French Polynesia', 'AAA'));
// ... push the other cities
```

And a search function:

```
function GetCity(cityToSearch, cities){
  var res = null;
  for(i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
    if(cities[i].city = cityToSearch
      res = cities[i]; 
  }
  return res;
}
```

At run time:

```
var codeFound = '';
var cityFound = GetCity('Arraias');
if(cityFound != null)
  codeFound = cityFound.cityCode;
```

**Remark**

In both case, if you are going to fill the cities array with all city of the world, the city name is not a key! For instance there are half a dozen of 'Springfield' in USA. In that case a better approach is to use a two-fields key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to accomplish this in a few simple steps:

1. Split each string in your array before and after the first parenthesis
2. Apply your first regex to the first part of the string.  Store the result as a boolean variable, perhaps named *matchOne*
3. Apply your second regex to the second part of the string (don't forget to remove the closing parenthesis).  Store the result as a boolean variable, perhaps named *matchTwo*.
4. Test if either of the two mathes succeeded: `return ( matchOne || matchTwo );`

Answer (score 0):

**Use indexOf**

Its more efficient and explicit of expectation. regex is unnecessary.

```js
const isMatchX = cityList.indexOf('AAB');
const isMatchY = cityList.indexOf('Awar');
```

Alternatively you could so something like this but its way overkill when you can use indexOf:

```js
const search = (cityList, re) => {
  const strRegPart1 = "¬[^¬]*" + re + "[^¬]*";
  const strRegPart2 = "¬[^¬]*\\([^\\)]*" + re + "[^\\)]*\\)($|¬)";
  const regSearch = RegExp("(" + strRegPart1 + "|" + strRegPart2 + ")", "gi");
  const strCityListMarked = '¬' + cityList.join('¬');
  const arrMatch = strCityListMarked.match(regSearch);
  return arrMatch && arrMatch[1].substr(1);
}
```